# WSDL to JSON-RPC in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, soap, wsdl

Hi
I have a web service which supports both RPC formats - JSON and SOAP. Does someone know tools which can generate client side code for JSON based on WSDL file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992456/sample-code-for-json-rpc-client-in-c ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sample code for JSON-RPC client in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992456/sample-code-for-json-rpc-client-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't know a tool for that, but it seems like a do-able task.

Problem with JSON-RPC is the lack of a description specification. [JSON-WSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsonwsp) has a description specification like SOAP's WSDL.

The only current implementation is in [Ladon](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ladon) which also supports SOAP and can generate WSDL files. Ladon includes a javascript client that can parse JSON-WSP descriptions and create a client proxy object, so call your service directly from a client browser.

The flipside is that Ladon is a Python framework so currently ypu must write all your service methods in Python or at least wrap your services in Python methods.